# How to check that smart card is working on linux?

Tags: linux, smartcard, pkcs#11

I've a PKCS-11 supported smartcard? I just want to check that my the smartcard is working fine or not. How can check it on Ubuntu? Please guide me. what software I can use? how what steps should I follow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is important to understand that **PKCS#11 standard just defines the C language API** to access smartcards and other types of cryptographic hardware (or even software). It is usually hardware vendor who provides software library (.dll for windows, .so for unix etc.) that implements PKCS#11 API and is able to access the hardware (smartcard in your case). Your application usually loads PKCS#11 library and uses PKCS#11 API functions it provides.

In most cases it is the best to use PKCS#11 library provided by your smartcard vendor but there are also many independent software vendors such as [A.E.T.](http://www.aeteurope.nl/) or [Aloaha](http://www.aloaha.com/) who provide smartcard middleware (software package that usually contains PKCS#11 library) that can access a bunch of widely used smartcards. You can also take a look at [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki) project which provides an open source PKCS#11 library that supports [many popular smartcards and USB tokens](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Supported-hardware-%28smart-cards-and-USB-tokens%29).

Now let's get back to your questions:

> Do I have a PKCS-11 supported smartcard?

You have to check whether there exists a library (open source or commercial) that implements PKCS#11 API and supports your smartcard. If you can find such a library then the answer is yes.

> How can I check it on Ubuntu?

If you already have PKCS#11 library then you can install "opensc" package which provides command line application called "pkcs11-tool". You can use following command to list readers and cards accessible via your PKCS#11 library:

```
pkcs11-tool --module your_pkcs11_library.so --list-slots
```

If you want to use PKCS#11 library provided by OpenSC project then just replace "your_pkcs11_library.so" with "opensc-pkcs11.so".

> What software I can use?

PKCS#11 is widely supported standard so this question is hard to answer. I guess you would like to use open source applications with your smartcard because you have mentioned Ubuntu so here is the short list of well known applications that support PKCS#11:

- Mozilla Firefox - supports digital signature and client authentication
- Mozilla Thunderbird - supports digital signing of e-mails
- LibreOffice - supports digital signing of documents
- TrueCrypt - supports disk encryption
- OpenVPN - supports client authentication
- OpenSSH - supports client authentication

Comment: Nice answer, jariq. For programming you can of course use either the OpenSSL PKCS#11 engine for C++ compatible environments or the Java (limited use only, such as key/certificate store, signing, authentication & encryption) PKCS#11 provider.

Answer (score 12):

To verify Ubuntu sees your smartcard reader and identity card:

1. Install libusb-1.0-0-dev pcsc-lite pcscd pcsc-tools

The following tools will be installed:

- pcscd - systemctl status pcscd  -  sometimes the card reader crashes this daemon, so you may need to restart it.
- opensc-explorer - it searches and displays smartcard readers attached
- opensc-tool - Options will provide detailed information about your smartcard reader.
- pcsc_scan - will show you smartcard reader and its status.  It should show your identity card inserted, as well as when you take it out.  If it displays waiting on reader - restart the pcscd service and try again.

The following link describes this more in detail and setting up firefox/chrome for certificates 
https://cubiclenate.com/linux/applications/utilities/dod-cac-ubuntu-linuxmint/